# Adding Custom type fields to in-memory TClientDataSet in Delphi

Tags: delphi, dataset, delphi-7, tclientdataset, delphi-6

I have a TClientDataSet which I want to add a custom type like the following to its field definition:

```
  TDay = (Mon=1, Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri, Sat, Sun);
```

Now I define my Dataset like the following:

```
  aDataSet := TClientDataSet.Create(nil);
  with aDataSet do
  begin
    FieldDefs.Add('Reference', ftString, 8);
    FieldDefs.Add('Archived',ftString,3);
    FieldDefs.Add('Problem', ftWideString, 48);
    FieldDefs.Add('Solution', ftWideString, 70);
    //FieldDefs.Add('Day', Tday type?????? // is it even possible?
    IndexFieldNames := 'Reference';
    CreateDataSet;
  end;
```

How can I associate each column with TDay and have a TDay type Column? Is it even possible doing this?

Comment: That is not possible as far as I know. However, you can store ordinal values of that enumeration into an integer field.

Comment: You can't do this, I'm afraid. The only FieldType values that are allowed are the ones already defined (ftString, ftInteger, etc.); there's no support for creating your own without writing your own TField and TClientDataSet descendants to support them, and for what you're wanting to do this would be a major endeavor that probably wouldn't be worth the effort. Use an ftSmallInt or ftInteger field, and enforce the allowed range in one of the dataset's events.

Comment: What would you use to store above in memory? A TList? What are my alternatives?

Comment: one can enforce the allowed range (1-7) even without touching any dataset event just by setting MinValue/MaxValue/CustomConstraint field's properties